# Payflow payment integration in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I'm using `paypal` for payment and here is main function and parameters which are used for payment.

```
def self.paypal_url(.....)
values = {
        :business => 'email@id.com',
        :cmd => '_cart',
        :upload => 1,
        :return => return_url,
        :invoice => "#{customer.id}_#{sType.id}_#{Time.now}",
        :notify_url => notify_url
    }
    values.merge!({
                      "amount_1" => amount,
                      "item_name_1" => sType.show_title,
                      "discount_amount_1" => discount
                      # "quantity_1" => '1'
                  })
    "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

But now i want to use `PayFlow`. Kindly guide me which parameter i have to change and what will be the final url as for payment is `"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query`.

Kindly guide me?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Rails example of payflow pro with hosted pages on git:
https://gist.github.com/supairish/5872581

The code gets the token to use in an iframe in your view.

You can see an example here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

I also found this resource helpful:
How do I test my integration with the Payflow Gateway using the hosted pages?
www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1493